# Problema com a função randint

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, estou tendo um pequeno problema no meu código. Eu tento gerar uma lista de 4 números inteiros aleatórios que não se repetem, mas...

```
list_num = []
c = 0
v = random.randint(0, 9)

while c < 4 and v not in list_num:
    list_num.append(v)
    c += 1
    v = random.randint(0, 9) # O problema está aqui
```

Ao tentar executar a linha `v = random.randint(0, 9)` dentro do loop, o conteúdo que já existia na variável `v` não é substituído pelo conteúdo novo gerado pelo código. Observei isso ao executá-lo no python tutor. O que pode estar causando o erro?

Comment: Executei esse código no shell, e ele funcionou sem problemas (ex.: `[8, 0, 2, 9]`). Provavelmente o problema está no python tutor... (há também uma chance em 10 do segundo valor ser idêntico ao primeiro entretanto, mas isso não vem ao caso) Executei o código duas vezes no pythontutor.com e tive `6` em ambas - mostrando que ele provavelmente não está gerando números aleatórios como deveria. A razão disso eu desconheço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está se referindo ao site http://www.pythontutor.com/, o problema é que ele provavelmente está usando uma semente fixa no seu gerador de números aleatórios. Meu palpite é que isso está sendo feito para que os resultados sejam sempre determinísticos. Por azar, as duas primeiras chamadas de `random.randint(0,9)` retornaram o mesmo valor (`6`) para a semente utilizada (1 chance em 10 de acontecer, e aconteceu!) e por isso *pareceu* que o valor não foi sobrescrito, quando na verdade foi.

Experimente atribuir você mesmo uma semente para o `random`, e você deve ter resultados diferentes. No meu caso, [consegui uma lista com 4 elementos](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+random%0D%0Arandom.seed(10)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alist_num+%3D+%5B%5D%0D%0Ac+%3D+0%0D%0Av+%3D+random.randint(0,+9)%0D%0A%0D%0Awhile+c+%3C+4+and+v+not+in+list_num%3A%0D%0A++++list_num.append(v)%0D%0A++++c+%2B%3D+1%0D%0A++++v+%3D+random.randint(0,+9)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=22) usando:

```
import random
random.seed(10);

list_num = []
c = 0
v = random.randint(0, 9)

while c < 4 and v not in list_num:
    list_num.append(v)
    c += 1
    v = random.randint(0, 9)
```

Você sempre pode, é claro, usar o relógio como semente, para que a execução seja diferente toda vez.

E quanto ao problema original ("gerar uma lista de 4 números inteiros aleatórios que não se repetem"), esse código precisa ser adaptado, pois ele simplesmente está parando quando encontra o primeiro que se repete... Sugiro o seguinte: (**cuidado:** se o número de elementos que você pedir for maior que o número de elementos disponíveis, esse código vai entrar num loop infinito)

```
while c < 4:
    while v in list_num:
        v = random.randint(0, 9)
    list_num.append(v)
    c += 1
```

[Experimentei no python tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+random%0D%0A%0D%0Alist_num+%3D+%5B%5D%0D%0Ac+%3D+0%0D%0Av+%3D+random.randint(0,+9)%0D%0A%0D%0Awhile+c+%3C+4%3A%0D%0A++++while+v+in+list_num%3A%0D%0A++++++++v+%3D+random.randint(0,+9)%0D%0A++++list_num.append(v)%0D%0A++++c+%2B%3D+1&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=29) sem usar semente alguma, e obtive `[6, 0, 4, 8]`.

Answer (score 2):

Salve amigo, segue código números aleatórios sem repetições. Espero que te ajude

```
import random
lista = []
while len(lista) < 4:
    x = random.randint(1, 50)
    if x not in lista:
        lista.append(x)
lista.sort()     #Aqui ele vai ordenar em crescente do menor para o maior.
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor estratégia para sortearmos números inteiros, aleatórios e sem repetições é utilizando o método **[sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)** da biblioteca **[random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)**. Desta forma, podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from random import sample

list_num = sorted(sample(range(0, 9), 4))
print(list_num)
```

Observe que quando executamos este código, o método **sample** irá sortear **4** números inteiros, aleatórios e sem repeticões, pertencentes ao **range(0, 9)** e, em seguida, com o auxílio da função **sorted**, ordenará os elementos em ordem crescente, para posteriormente, exibi-los.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** Como a função **[range()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#range)** do python inicia no `limite inferior` e vai até o `limite superio - 1`, significando dizer que, para o **range(0, 9)**, serão sorteados valores entre **0 e 9 - 1**, ou seja, valores entre **0 e 8**.